# GQL schema not returning nested objects

Tags: graphql, apollo-client

Below is the response which I get from Rest API.

```
{
  'metadata': {
    'cache': '600',
  },
  "data": [{
    "name": "Content",
    "content": {
      "title": "Legal information",
      "paragraphs": [
        {
          "title": "Website terms of use1",
          "text": "Sample Text",
        }]
    }
  }]
}
```

My GQL schema looks like this,

```
type Metadata {
  cache: String
}

type Content {
  metadata: Metadata
  data
}
```

I wanted GQL, to send me whatever inside `data` with out any schema .

How can it be done please help

Answer (score 0):

GraphQL doesn't work that way.  You have to provide a complete definition of every concrete object type you might return.

Some other SO answers have suggested tricks like declaring a `scalar JSON` and then serializing free-form data into a JSON string and returning that, but that becomes difficult to use.  (You can't directly query fields inside a `data: String` field even if it does happen to be encoded as JSON.)

As you're describing the problem you might be better off just exposing the backend REST API directly, rather than try to wrap it in a vague GraphQL facade.